# Javascript to allow Clicked Image to enter a Textaera with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

Can anybody please tell me what is wrong with the following code?

```js
< form method = "POST"
id = "postform"
name = "postform"
enctype = "multipart/form-data" >
  < label > Title < label > < br / >
  < input type = "text"
name = "title"
id = "postformtitle"
value = "<?php echo htmlentities($ptitle); ?>"
maxlength = "90" / > < br / >
  < script type = "text/javascript" > document.postform.title.focus() < /script>
<label>Body/Content < /label>
<div id="editbar" style="display:block"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick='wrapText("body", "[b]", "[/b]")' title="Bold">
<span class="eb"><img src="<?php $set['url']; ?>/icon / bold.gif "/></span></a>
<a href="
javascript: void(0);
" onclick='wrapText("
body ", " [i]
", " [/i]")' title="Italic">
<span class="eb"><img src="<?php $set['url']; ?>/icon / italicize.gif "/></span></a>
<a href="
  javascript: void(0);
  " onclick='wrapText("
  body ", " [s]
  ", " [/s]")' title="Strikethrough">
<span class="eb"><img src="<?php $set['url']; ?>/icon / strike.gif "/></span></a>
<a href="
    javascript: void(0);
    " onclick='wrapText("
    body ", " [left]
    ", " [/left]")' title="Align Left">
<span class="eb"><img src="<?php $set['url']; ?>/icon / left.gif "/></span></a>
<a href="
      javascript: void(0);
      " onclick='wrapText("
      body ", " [right]
      ", " [/right]")' title="Align Right">

<span class="eb"><img src="<?php $set['url']; ?>/icon / right.gif "/></span></a>
<a href="
        javascript: void(0);
        " onclick='wrapText("
        body ", " [center]
        ", " [/center]")' title="Align Center">
<span class="eb"><img src="<?php $set['url']; ?>/icon / center.gif "/></span></a>
<a href="
          javascript: void(0);
          " onclick='addText("
          body ", " [hr]
          ")' title="
          Horizontal Rule ">
<span class="
          eb "><img src=" <? php $set['url']; ?> /icon/hr.gif "/></span></a>
<a href="
          javascript: void(0);
          " onclick='wrapText("
          body ", " [size = 8pt]
          ", " [/size]")' title="Font Size">
<span class="eb"><img src="<?php $set['url']; ?>/icon / size.gif "/></span></a>
<a href="
            javascript: void(0);
            " onclick='wrapText("
            body ", " [font = Lucida Sans Unicode]
            ", " [/font]")' title="Font Face">
<span class="eb"><img src="<?php $set['url']; ?>/icon / face.gif "/></span></a>
<a href="
              javascript: void(0);
              " onclick='wrapText("
              body ", " [img]
              ", " [/img]")' title="Insert Image/Picture
                ">
<span class="
                eb "><img src=" <? php $set['url']; ?> /icon/img.gif "></span></a>
<a href="
                javascript: void(0);
                " onclick='wrapText("
                body ", " [url]
                ", " [/url]")' title="Insert Hyperlink">
<span class="eb"><img src="<?php $set['url']; ?>/icon / url.gif "/></span></a>
<a href="
                  javascript: void(0);
                  " onclick='wrapText("
                  body ", " [email]
                  ", " [/email]")' title="Insert Email">
<span class="eb"><img src="<?php $set['url']; ?>/icon / email.gif "/></span></a>
<a href="
                    javascript: void(0);
                    " onclick='wrapText("
                    body ", " [sub]
                    ", " [/sub]")' title="Subscript">
<span class="eb"><img src="<?php $set['url']; ?>/icon / sub.gif "/></span></a>
<a href="
                      javascript: void(0);
                      " onclick='wrapText("
                      body ", " [sup]
                      ", " [/sup]")' title="Superscript">
<span class="eb"><img src="<?php $set['url']; ?>/icon / sup.gif "/></span></a>

<a href="
                        javascript: void(0);
                        " onclick='wrapText("
                        body ", " [code]
                        ", " [/code]")' title="Code">
<span class="eb"><img src="<?php $set['url']; ?>/icon / code.gif "/></span></a>
<a href="
                          javascript: void(0);
                          " onclick='wrapText("
                          body ", " [quote]
                          ", " [/quote]")' title="Quote">
<span class="eb"><img src="<?php $set['url']; ?>/icon / quote.gif "/></span></a>
<a href="
                            javascript: void(0);
                            " onclick='addText("
                            body ", ": )
                          ")'><img src=" <? php $set['url']; ?> /icon/smiley.png " class="
                          faces "/></a>
<a href="
                          javascript: void(0);
                          " onclick='addText("
                          body ", ";)
                        ")'><img src=" <? php $set['url']; ?> /icon/wink.png " class="
                        faces "/></a>
<a href="
                        javascript: void(0);
                        " onclick='addText("
                        body ", ": D ")'><img src=" <? php $set['url']; ?> /icon/cheesy.png " class="
                        faces "/></a>
<a href="
                        javascript: void(0);
                        " onclick='addText("
                        body ", ";D ")'><img src=" <? php $set['url']; ?> /icon/grin.png " class="
                        faces "/></a>
<a href="
                        javascript: void(0);
                        " onclick='addText("
                        body ", "
                        5)
                      ")'><img src=" <? php $set['url']; ?> /icon/angry.png " class="
                      faces "/></a>
<a href="
                      javascript: void(0);
                      " onclick='addText("
                      body ", ": (")'><img src=" <? php $set['url']; ?> /icon/sad.png " class="
                        faces "/></a>
<a href="
                        javascript: void(0);
                        " onclick='addText("
                        body ", ": o ")'><img src=" <? php $set['url']; ?> /icon/shocked.gif " class="
                        faces "/></a>
<a href="
                        javascript: void(0);
                        " onclick='addText("
                        body ", "
                        8)
                      ")'><img src=" <? php $set['url']; ?> /icon/cool.png " class="
                      faces "/></a>
<a href="
                      javascript: void(0);
                      " onclick='addText("
                      body ", " ? ? ? ")'><img src=" <? php $set['url']; ?> /icon/huh.png " style="
                      width : 15px;height : 22px;
                      "/></a>
<a href="
                      javascript : void(0);
                      " onclick='addText("
                      body ", ": P ")'><img src=" <? php $set['url']; ?> /icon/tongue.png " class="
                      faces "/></a>
<a href="
                      javascript: void(0);
                      " onclick='addText("
                      body ", ": -[")'><img src=" <? php $set['url']; ?> /icon/embarassed.png " class="
                        faces "/></a>
<a href="
                        javascript: void(0);
                        " onclick='addText("
                        body ", ": -X ")'><img src=" <? php $set['url']; ?> /icon/lipsrsealed.png " class="
                        faces "/></a>
<a href="
                        javascript: void(0);
                        " onclick='addText("
                        body ", ": -\\")'><img src=" <? php $set['url']; ?> /icon/undecided.png " class="
                        faces "/></a>

<a href="
                        javascript: void(0);
                        " onclick='addText("
                        body ", ": - * ")'><img src=" <? php $set['url']; ?> /icon/kiss.gif " class="
                        faces "/></a>
<a href="
                        javascript: void(0);
                        " onclick='addText("
                        body ", ";
                        (")'><img src=" <? php $set['url']; ?> /icon/cry.gif " class="
                          faces "/></a>
<select onchange="
                          wrapText('body', '[color=' + this.options[this.selectedIndex].value + ']', '[/color]'); this.selectedIndex = 0;
                          " style="
                          margin - bottom: 1ex;
                          ">
<option value="
                          " selected="
                          selected ">Change Color</option>
<option value="
                          #990000">Red</option>
<option value= "#006600" > Green < /option>
<option value="#000099">Blue</option >
                          < option value = "#770077" > Purple < /option>
<option value="#550000">Brown</option >
                          < option value = "#000000" > Black < /option>
<option value="#FFA500">Orange</option >
                          < option value = "#2B1B17" > Midnight < /option>
<option value="#00FFFF">Cyan</option >
                          < option value = "#808080" > Grey < /option>
<option value="#C0C0C0">Silver</option >
                          < option value = "#800000" > Maroon < /option>
<option value="#00FF00">Lime</option > < /select>

</div >
                          < script > document.getElementById("editbar").style.display = 'block'; < /script>
<textarea rows="8" name="body" id="body"><?php echo htmlentities($body); ?> </textarea > < br / >
                          < br / > < input type = "submit"
                          name = "addpos"
                          accesskey = s value = "Add Post" / > < /form> </div >
```

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick='addText("body", " :-\\")'><img src="<?php $set['url']; ?>/icon/undecided.png" class="faces"/></a>
```

Comment: its not our job to deobfuscate + understand your code, its yours to explain it to us and do simple debugging

Comment: i am not the developer but it is for allow image value to enter a texarea after it has been clicked demo is in the jsfiddle link above

Comment: thats not helpful at all. may pay a real dev to help you, if you cannot tell us what the code does, we cannot help you. sorry

Answer (score 0):

Try this code at your end. Not here. Tell me if the problem is solved.

```js
< form method = "POST"
id = "postform"
name = "postform"
enctype = "multipart/form-data" >
  < label > Title < label > < br / >
  < input type = "text"
name = "title"
id = "postformtitle"
value = "<?php echo htmlentities($ptitle); ?>"
maxlength = "90" / > < br / >
  < script type = "text/javascript" > document.postform.title.focus(); </script>
<label>Body/Content < /label>
<div id="editbar" style="display:block"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick='wrapText("body", "[b]", "[/b]")' title="Bold">
<span class="eb"><img src="<?php $set['url']; ?>/icon / bold.gif "/></span></a>
<a href="
javascript: void(0);
" onclick='wrapText("
body ", " [i]
", " [/i]")' title="Italic">
<span class="eb"><img src="<?php $set['url']; ?>/icon / italicize.gif "/></span></a>
<a href="
  javascript: void(0);
  " onclick='wrapText("
  body ", " [s]
  ", " [/s]")' title="Strikethrough">
<span class="eb"><img src="<?php $set['url']; ?>/icon / strike.gif "/></span></a>
<a href="
    javascript: void(0);
    " onclick='wrapText("
    body ", " [left]
    ", " [/left]")' title="Align Left">
<span class="eb"><img src="<?php $set['url']; ?>/icon / left.gif "/></span></a>
<a href="
      javascript: void(0);
      " onclick='wrapText("
      body ", " [right]
      ", " [/right]")' title="Align Right">

<span class="eb"><img src="<?php $set['url']; ?>/icon / right.gif "/></span></a>
<a href="
        javascript: void(0);
        " onclick='wrapText("
        body ", " [center]
        ", " [/center]")' title="Align Center">
<span class="eb"><img src="<?php $set['url']; ?>/icon / center.gif "/></span></a>
<a href="
          javascript: void(0);
          " onclick='addText("
          body ", " [hr]
          ")' title="
          Horizontal Rule ">
<span class="
          eb "><img src=" <? php $set['url']; ?> /icon/hr.gif "/></span></a>
<a href="
          javascript: void(0);
          " onclick='wrapText("
          body ", " [size = 8pt]
          ", " [/size]")' title="Font Size">
<span class="eb"><img src="<?php $set['url']; ?>/icon / size.gif "/></span></a>
<a href="
            javascript: void(0);
            " onclick='wrapText("
            body ", " [font = Lucida Sans Unicode]
            ", " [/font]")' title="Font Face">
<span class="eb"><img src="<?php $set['url']; ?>/icon / face.gif "/></span></a>
<a href="
              javascript: void(0);
              " onclick='wrapText("
              body ", " [img]
              ", " [/img]")' title="Insert Image/Picture
                ">
<span class="
                eb "><img src=" <? php $set['url']; ?> /icon/img.gif "></span></a>
<a href="
                javascript: void(0);
                " onclick='wrapText("
                body ", " [url]
                ", " [/url]")' title="Insert Hyperlink">
<span class="eb"><img src="<?php $set['url']; ?>/icon / url.gif "/></span></a>
<a href="
                  javascript: void(0);
                  " onclick='wrapText("
                  body ", " [email]
                  ", " [/email]")' title="Insert Email">
<span class="eb"><img src="<?php $set['url']; ?>/icon / email.gif "/></span></a>
<a href="
                    javascript: void(0);
                    " onclick='wrapText("
                    body ", " [sub]
                    ", " [/sub]")' title="Subscript">
<span class="eb"><img src="<?php $set['url']; ?>/icon / sub.gif "/></span></a>
<a href="
                      javascript: void(0);
                      " onclick='wrapText("
                      body ", " [sup]
                      ", " [/sup]")' title="Superscript">
<span class="eb"><img src="<?php $set['url']; ?>/icon / sup.gif "/></span></a>

<a href="
                        javascript: void(0);
                        " onclick='wrapText("
                        body ", " [code]
                        ", " [/code]")' title="Code">
<span class="eb"><img src="<?php $set['url']; ?>/icon / code.gif "/></span></a>
<a href="
                          javascript: void(0);
                          " onclick='wrapText("
                          body ", " [quote]
                          ", " [/quote]")' title="Quote">
<span class="eb"><img src="<?php $set['url']; ?>/icon / quote.gif "/></span></a>
<a href="
                            javascript: void(0);
                            " onclick='addText("
                            body ", ": )
                          ")'><img src=" <? php $set['url']; ?> /icon/smiley.png " class="
                          faces "/></a>
<a href="
                          javascript: void(0);
                          " onclick='addText("
                          body ", ";)
                        ")'><img src=" <? php $set['url']; ?> /icon/wink.png " class="
                        faces "/></a>
<a href="
                        javascript: void(0);
                        " onclick='addText("
                        body ", ": D ")'><img src=" <? php $set['url']; ?> /icon/cheesy.png " class="
                        faces "/></a>
<a href="
                        javascript: void(0);
                        " onclick='addText("
                        body ", ";D ")'><img src=" <? php $set['url']; ?> /icon/grin.png " class="
                        faces "/></a>
<a href="
                        javascript: void(0);
                        " onclick='addText("
                        body ", "
                        5)
                      ")'><img src=" <? php $set['url']; ?> /icon/angry.png " class="
                      faces "/></a>
<a href="
                      javascript: void(0);
                      " onclick='addText("
                      body ", ": (")'><img src=" <? php $set['url']; ?> /icon/sad.png " class="
                        faces "/></a>
<a href="
                        javascript: void(0);
                        " onclick='addText("
                        body ", ": o ")'><img src=" <? php $set['url']; ?> /icon/shocked.gif " class="
                        faces "/></a>
<a href="
                        javascript: void(0);
                        " onclick='addText("
                        body ", "
                        8)
                      ")'><img src=" <? php $set['url']; ?> /icon/cool.png " class="
                      faces "/></a>
<a href="
                      javascript: void(0);
                      " onclick='addText("
                      body ", " ? ? ? ")'><img src=" <? php $set['url']; ?> /icon/huh.png " style="
                      width : 15px;height : 22px;
                      "/></a>
<a href="
                      javascript : void(0);
                      " onclick='addText("
                      body ", ": P ")'><img src=" <? php $set['url']; ?> /icon/tongue.png " class="
                      faces "/></a>
<a href="
                      javascript: void(0);
                      " onclick='addText("
                      body ", ": -[")'><img src=" <? php $set['url']; ?> /icon/embarassed.png " class="
                        faces "/></a>
<a href="
                        javascript: void(0);
                        " onclick='addText("
                        body ", ": -X ")'><img src=" <? php $set['url']; ?> /icon/lipsrsealed.png " class="
                        faces "/></a>
<a href="
                        javascript: void(0);
                        " onclick='addText("
                        body ", ": -\\")'><img src=" <? php $set['url']; ?> /icon/undecided.png " class="
                        faces "/></a>

<a href="
                        javascript: void(0);
                        " onclick='addText("
                        body ", ": - * ")'><img src=" <? php $set['url']; ?> /icon/kiss.gif " class="
                        faces "/></a>
<a href="
                        javascript: void(0);
                        " onclick='addText("
                        body ", ";
                        (")'><img src=" <? php $set['url']; ?> /icon/cry.gif " class="
                          faces "/></a>
<select onchange="
                          wrapText('body', '[color=' + this.options[this.selectedIndex].value + ']', '[/color]'); this.selectedIndex = 0;
                          " style="
                          margin - bottom: 1ex;
                          ">
<option value="
                          " selected="
                          selected ">Change Color</option>
<option value="
                          #990000">Red</option>
<option value= "#006600" > Green < /option>
<option value="#000099">Blue</option >
                          < option value = "#770077" > Purple < /option>
<option value="#550000">Brown</option >
                          < option value = "#000000" > Black < /option>
<option value="#FFA500">Orange</option >
                          < option value = "#2B1B17" > Midnight < /option>
<option value="#00FFFF">Cyan</option >
                          < option value = "#808080" > Grey < /option>
<option value="#C0C0C0">Silver</option >
                          < option value = "#800000" > Maroon < /option>
<option value="#00FF00">Lime</option > < /select>

</div >
                          < script > document.getElementById("editbar").style.display = 'block'; < /script>
<textarea rows="8" name="body" id="body"><?php echo htmlentities($body); ?> </textarea > < br / >
                          < br / > < input type = "submit"
                          name = "addpos"
                          accesskey = s value = "Add Post" / > < /form> </div >
```

Comment: @FlashWebTechInc Yeah that's why I asked you to test this code at your dev server not here. because there some php lines in this code which are messing with it